# access parameters in service function

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to use some parameters stored in the parameter server within a **service function.** I tried a lot to **pass the nodeHandle** as an additional parameter with functions from the boost library, but it didn't work. Can anyone give me some advice how to correctly access the NodeHandle, which is created in the main function, within the service function whenever the service is called?
It would be nice if I could get a working example how to achieve this. I program the nodes in C++.

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296379/access-parameters-in-service-function/) by [Matthi](https://answers.ros.org/users/36260/matthi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you mean the service callback with `service function`.

Basically you have to possibilities.

1. If you really want to use the `NodeHandle` that is created outside the service callback, make this a member variable (if you are using a class) and just access that, or make it a global variable (if you don't have a class). No need to pass it to the service callback.
2. You can just create a new `NodeHandle` in the scope of the service callback. You can have as many `NodeHandle`s as you want. And then use this to retrieve the parameter. Again, no need to pass it in.

Thus, my suggestion would be to use 1 if you have a class (obviously, the service callback needs to be a member function of the class as well) and 2 if you don't.

(As both ways are trivial, I'll not provide example code for now.)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yashtrikannad](https://answers.ros.org/users/45515/yashtrikannad/) on 2019-11-23**:
I am not able to call class member functions in the service. It shows that the callback is not a non-static member of the class. If I try to make the callback function static, I will not be able to access the class members(parameters). So I am not sure if the first option will work?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-11-24**:
You can pass member function pointer and object when creating the service; then the service handler can be a non-static member function and use class members.